# Is there a way to get an uniform distribution from a gauss distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random

I have seen some implementations of "true" random number generators. However they are all producing a gauss distribution. I have asked myself, if it would be possible to run these numbers through some sort of algorithm, so that one can get an uniform distribution in the end?

I guess it is impossible, can someone explain to me, why?

Comment: Relevant: [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). (You can generalize this to your setting)

Comment: *"However they are all producing a gauss distribution."* - What is that claim based on?

Comment: Well the ones I have looked at did..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by *Clement C.* is all you need. Let $F(\cdot)$ be the cdf of a r.v. $X$ that is normally distributed. Then the random variable $Y =F(X)$ is uniformly distributed. So if you know how to sample $x$ from $X$, transform the result to $y=F(x)$ and this is equivalent to sampling from a uniform distribution.

Most implementations work the other way around. They sample from a uniform $X$ and use the transform to generate another distribution. I suspect this is also what happens behind the scenes for the "gauss distributions" you refer to.